# Failed: dbName.collectionName: error restoring from collectionName.bson: reading bson input: unexpected EOF

Tags: linux, mongodb, mongorestore, mongodb4.0

I have an error when try to restore a 32GB database in MongoDB. I've tried the following commands but none of them works:

`mongorestore --db prod --drop --dir backup-cloud-server/20200221020001/prod --batchSize=1`

`mongorestore --db prod --drop --dir backup-cloud-server/20200221020001/prod --batchSize=10`

`mongorestore --db prod --drop --dir backup-cloud-server/20200221020001/prod --batchSize=100`

`mongorestore --db prod --drop --dir backup-cloud-server/20200221020001/prod --batchSize=1000`

```
    [#######################.]  DbName.CollectionName  31.4 GB/32.2 GB  (98.7%)
    [#######################.]  DbName.CollectionName  31.7 GB/32.2 GB  (99.0%)
    [#######################.]  DbName.CollectionName  32.9 GB/32.2 GB  (99.3%)
    [#######################.]  DbName.CollectionName  32.1 GB/32.2 GB  (99.5%)
    [#######################.]  DbName.CollectionName  32.2 GB/32.2 GB  (99.8%)
    restoring indexes for collection DbName.CollectionName from metadata
    Failed: restore error: DbName.CollectionName: error creating indexes for DbName.CollectionName: createIndex error: EOF
```

I've also tried to change the wiredTiger cachedSize to 4GB according to this suggestion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/Ms2MXCajreg/OsW6ixcSCgAJ but it did not worked.

Any suggestion?

My machine / enviromnent:

OS: MAC OS X 10.14.6

RAM: 32GB

free disk: 80GB

mongod version: v4.2.2

mongorestore version: r4.2.2

EDIT: 
Here with the `--noIndexRestore` flag

```
2020-03-05T14:43:06.588+0100    [#######################.]  dbname.CollectionName  31.7GB/32.2GB  (98.5%)
2020-03-05T14:43:09.588+0100    [#######################.]  dbname.CollectionName  31.9GB/32.2GB  (99.1%)
2020-03-05T14:43:12.588+0100    [#######################.]  dbname.CollectionName  32.1GB/32.2GB  (99.8%)
2020-03-05T14:43:13.286+0100    [########################]  dbname.CollectionName  32.2GB/32.2GB  (100.0%)
2020-03-05T14:43:13.286+0100    finished restoring dbname.CollectionName (12660301 documents, 0 failures)
2020-03-05T14:43:13.286+0100    Failed: dbname.CollectionName: error restoring from backup/20200221020001/dbname/CollectionName.bson: reading bson input: unexpected EOF
2020-03-05T14:43:13.286+0100    12667254 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Comment: Did you try to restore the dump without automatically recreating the indexes? The `--noIndexRestore` option should help you with that. If it works you can try to recreate the indexes afterwards.

Comment: That error sounds like the dump wasn't quite complete, or was damage after it was made.

Comment: @joe the dump was made correctly no error was shown, and all files were in the folder correctly. I highly doubt that this is the problem.

Comment: @joe I will re-dump it anyway to try

Comment: @lonut Ticus I've edited the answer with your suggestion

Comment: Is the number of restored documents correct? Can you try again and monitor memory / disk usage when it's nearing completion?